# Перевод баланса на сайте

Tags: php, sql

Появилась такая проблема, есть функция перевода на сайте, но я могу перевести баланс любому человеку кроме себя введя абслоютно любую сумму, у меня она уйдет в минус, а человеку, которому отправляю, приходит. Как сделать так, что бы баланс проверялся, и если он меньше суммы заявленной или меньше нуля, значит вылезала ошибка, что такое сделать нельзя, либо если баланс больше или равен сумме которую надо перевести, то тогда успешно бы переводилось.
Вот код:

```
    if($row['login'] != $nick)
{
    $fa = 'error';
    $error = 'Пользователь не найден';
}else {
    if($rowa['login'] == $nick){
        $fa = 'error';
        $error = 'Вы не можете перевести самому себе';
    }else {
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $summa)){
            $fa = 'error';
            $error = 'Сумма заполнено неверно';
        }else {
            if($summa < 10)
            {
                $fa = 'error';
                $error = 'Минимальная сумма перевода 10 '.$walletsite.'';
            }else {
                $update_sql = "Update ".$prefix."_users set balance=balance + '$summa' WHERE login='$nick'";
                mysql_query($update_sql) or die("" . mysql_error());
                $update_sql = "Update ".$prefix."_users set balance=balance - '$summa' WHERE hash='$sid'";
                mysql_query($update_sql) or die("" . mysql_error());
                $fa = 'success';
                $error = 'Вы перевели '.$summa.' '.$walletsite.' пользователю '.$nick.'';
                $sql_selects = "SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_users WHERE hash='$sid'";
                $results = mysql_query($sql_selects);
                $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
                $new_balance = $rows['balance'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как сделать? Получить свой баланс из таблицы и сравнить с суммой перевода.

Answer (score 1):

Не вдаваясь в подробности остальных проверок, блок перевода денег может выглядеть как-то так (код не проверялся, работоспособность "как есть" не гарантируется):

```
function do_update($update_sql) {
    mysql_query($update_sql) or throw new Exception(mysql_error()); 
    return mysql_affected_rows(); // Возвращаем количество реально измененных строк
}

...

$Ok=0;
try {
    mysql_query("START TRANSACTION"); // Начинаем транзакцию, которая будет выполнена вся целиком или ничего из нее
    $ret=do_update("Update " . $prefix . "_users set balance=balance - $summa WHERE hash='$sid' AND balance - $summa >= 0");
    // Если денег не хватит, то запрос ничего не изменит и вернет 0 измененных строк
    if($ret != 1) throw new Exception("Недостаточно средств");
    $ret=do_update("Update " . $prefix . "_users set balance=balance + $summa WHERE login='$nick'");
    if($ret != 1) throw new Exception("Получатель средств не найден");
    $Ok=1;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Произошла ошибка при переводе: ', $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    mysql_query($Ok ? "COMMIT" : "ROLLBACK"); // Завершаем или откатываем транзакцию в зависимости от успешного завершения запроса
}
```

В дополнение замечу, что подстановка текста переменных непосредственно в текст запроса связана с массой потенциальных ошибок и возможностей SQL-инъекций. Кроме того, расширение mysql_ давно устарело и уже начинает исчезать с хостингов с новыми версиями php. Настоятельно рекомендую переходить на использование PDO и подготавливаемых выражений с [привязкой параметров](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['login'] != $nick) {
        $fa = 'error';
        $error = 'Пользователь не найден';
    } else {
        if ($rowa['login'] == $nick) {
            $fa = 'error';
            $error = 'Вы не можете перевести самому себе';
        } else {
            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $summa)) {
                $fa = 'error';
                $error = 'Сумма заполнено неверно';
            } else {
                if ($summa < 10) {
                    $fa = 'error';
                    $error = 'Минимальная сумма перевода 10 ' . $walletsite . '';
                } else {
                    $s1 = "SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "_users WHERE hash='$sid'";
                    $r1 = mysql_query($s1);
                    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($r1);
                    $my_balance = $rows['balance'];
                    if ($my_balance < $summa) {
                        $fa = 'error';
                        $error = 'У вас нету столько';
                    } else {
                        $update_sql = "Update " . $prefix . "_users set balance=balance + '$summa' WHERE login='$nick'";
                        mysql_query($update_sql) or die("" . mysql_error());
                        $update_sql = "Update " . $prefix . "_users set balance=balance - '$summa' WHERE hash='$sid'";
                        mysql_query($update_sql) or die("" . mysql_error());
                        $fa = 'success';
                        $error = 'Вы перевели ' . $summa . ' ' . $walletsite . ' пользователю ' . $nick . '';
                        $sql_selects = "SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "_users WHERE hash='$sid'";
                        $results = mysql_query($sql_selects);
                        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
                        $new_balance = $rows['balance'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так делать нельзя, особенно с деньгами. Как минимум надо включить на соединении поддержку транзакций (или включить на одну операцию с помощью `start transaction`) и читать текущий баланс с помощью `select for update`, что бы запись в БД была заблокирована на время проверки баланса. Иначе пользователь выполнив одновременно несколько операций может добиться ситуации, что вы прочитали один баланс, но он изменился перед тем как вы дали update. И он уйдет в минус.

Comment: Кроме того, при работе вне транзакции, есть вероятность что с mysql что то случится между первым и вторым update. И вы деньги спишите, но зачислить не сможете !

Comment: Плюс к этому нет проверки на существование пользователя которому происходит перевод. значит вы легко можете перевести деньги вникуда

Comment: Итого: предлагаю начать транзакцию. сделать `update set balance=balance - '$summa' WHERE hash='$sid' and balance - '$summa' > 0` (что бы ничего не могло сделать счет отрицательным). проверить не только на ошибки, но и на то, что изменена ровно 1 строка (см `mysql_affected_rows()`). Зачислить деньги на счет второму пользователю. Убедиться, что опять же модифицирована ровно одна строка. Если все прошло успешно - дать commit. Если что угодно пошло не так - rollback. Ну и предварительно не помешало бы проверить $summ и $nick на допустимость, что бы не создало SQL-инъекцию

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @Mike я конечно с тобой согласен но вопрос состоял в том чтобы пользователь не пошел в минус. и вообще для исключения инъекций лучше использовать PDO и также поддержка функций mysql прекращена несколько лет. я просто ответил на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @Arendach Но ваш код таки может уйти в минус если между select и update в БД кто то изменит баланс пользователя

Comment: @Mike мы не знаем есть ли такая возможность у программы(я о том что кто-то может менять баланс пользователя). у нас всего есть кусок кода. +между select и update проходит где-то около 0.001 - 0.10 сек. в этот промежуток времени сложно вцелить. и еще логично представить что баланс пользователя можно увеличить а не уменьшить. но опять мы не знаем.

Comment: Лучше исключить любую возможность ошибок на корню. Чем потом при расхождениях искать откуда они взялись.